# How to find the total no of instances and active instances under a single tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat, server, ping, multiple-instances

I want to know total number of instances and active instances running in a single tomcat server. Is it possible to do with ping localhost:8082.

i want to run some command get details about the instances in a single tomcat server. I will use nodejs and create an endpoint and from there i have to run a command and get the information and pass it back to client.

Comment: What is an instance?

Comment: i am sorry i if convey it wrong. suppose in tomcat, i am running 2-3 instances of same war file deployed in each instance and now i want to get the running instances details. how can i get by using ping or telnet any command is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by instance. But,if you mean that your site is deployed for number of countries and divided them to different instances(running each instance as a service). You should find the services under init.d

Comment: yes in different instances i am running same war but for now i am not using any load balancer. i just want to create a nodejs api if i hit that it should return me total instances and active instances running in tomcat server.